# Symfony / Doctrine - SQL to Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Can someone please help? I'm trying to create shopping cart and have this SQL, but I want it in Entity:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `total_price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `order_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

How could I create **order_items** in doctrine? It's many to many relation I think, but with 2 more columns.

Thank you

Comment: what did you try so far and where did you fail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Doctrine, if you want to have attributes attached to a **Many To Many** relationship, simply just create **another entity**. This entity will have two M-1 relationships linked to the other two entities, in the scenario of your question, you can have an **OrderItem** entity, which are associated with **Orders** and **Products** table via 1-M relationship (basically two foreign keys in SQL) and as many attributes for itself as you want.